# Externalize property configuration for log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j, gemfire

Background: I have log4j.xml file configured for our spring based application, which looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="FATAL" shutdownHook="disable" packages="com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.logging.log4j">
  <Properties>
<Property name="gemfire-pattern">[%level{lowerCase=true} %date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z} &lt;%thread&gt; tid=%tid %C{1.}] %message%n%throwable%n<    /Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${gemfire-pattern}"/>
    </Console>
      <RollingFile name="eventLogFile" fileName="/opt/data/service/logs/events.log"
                   filePattern="/opt/data/service/logs/events-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
          <PatternLayout>
              <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p - %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
          </PatternLayout>
          <Policies>
              <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
              <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
          </Policies>
          <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" fileIndex="max"/>
      </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.gemstone" level="INFO" additivity="true">
        <filters>
            <MarkerFilter marker="GEMFIRE_VERBOSE" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        </filters>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="com.app.mypackage" level="INFO" additivity="true">
       <AppenderRef ref="eventLogFile"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Now, I want log4j to write log statements with let's say 'countryName'. And, this 'countryName' should be configured via external property file.

For e.g, the "gemfire-pattern" will have this externalised property name $${countryName}.

```
<Property name="gemfire-pattern">[$${countryName} %level{lowerCase=true} %date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z} &lt;%thread&gt; tid=%tid %C{1.}] %message%n%throwable%n<    /Property>
```

Considering this [log4j system properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties), in my case, the `log4j.component.properties` is not being picked up by log4j.

Any thoughts on how to fetch a property value from external properties file in log4j.xml?

References:

- [how-to-read-property-variable-from-file-into-log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460824/log4j2-how-to-read-property-variable-from-file-into-log4j2)
- [log4j system properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties)
- [log4j properties substitution](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`log4j.component.properties` is used to add log4j specific system properties like `log4j.configurationFile`, `org.apache.logging.log4j.level` etc.

To refer to user defined properties, include the property file inside the logback configuration and refer to the keys using `${KEY}`

```html
<configuration>

  <property file="country.properties" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${countryName}</file>
  ...
```

Logback also allows you to externalise parts of the configuration using File inclusion feature.
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#fileInclusion

```html
<configuration>
  <include file="src/main/java/chapters/configuration/includedConfig.xml"/>
...
```

Make sure the content in the external xml file is encolsed with `<included> </included>` tag

**Note-** System properties(-Dcountry="") and Environment variables can also be referred using `${PROPERTY_NAME}` inside the logback configuration.